# Jenkins + Join Plugin + Git - Join target getting called twice

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm using the Jenkins Join Plugin with Git.  My join job config looks like:

git SVN polling job with config that looks like this: [image: Jenkins Join Config]
Here is a link to a larger version of the image:  http://cl.ly/PZg2

This mostly works, however, my Post Join build job which waits for some test jobs to finish gets called twice.  In the first call, the git revision gets passed correctly.  In the second call, it is not passed correctly (the revision would be the "latest" even if the calling jobs were on a different revision)

Does anyone know why the Post Join build job would get called twice?

Perhaps the join plugin doesn't play well with the Trigger Parameterized build on other projects?

Thanks for any thoughts....